# Trying to use window.ethereum.request in Typescript errors out with Property 'request' does not exist on type 'EthereumProvider'

Tags: metamask, typescript

Except for one unanswered question from last November, I cannot find anything . . . .

I am revamping some typescript code (in Visual Studio) for the Metamask January change.
Previously, I was using web3.  Now I am just trying to use window.ethereum.

I cannot find a DefinitelyTyped (or any other types) file with type declarations.

I fear that this is really something simple/stupid but I'm totally at a loss.

Comment: any solution, my window is null

Comment: Where did you get the type `EthereumProvider` in the first place?

Answer (score 11):

If you're doing this in React with CRA or ViteJS or even Remix-Run:

**File:** `src/vite-env.d.ts`

```js
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

interface Window {
  ethereum: any;
}
```

**File:** `src/react-app-env.d.ts`

```js
/// <reference types="react-scripts" />

interface Window {
  ethereum: any;
}
```

**File:** `/remix.env.d.ts`

```js
/// <reference types="@remix-run/dev" />
/// <reference types="@remix-run/node" />

interface Window {
  ethereum: any;
}
```

In case you are using ethers.js, you should consider using the type `import('ethers').Eip1193Provider` instead of `any`

Answer (score 8):

You can create a `global.d.ts` file at the root level of your project & type `window.ethereum` this way instead of using `any`.

```typescript
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: import('ethers').providers.ExternalProvider;
  }
}
```

If you're using ethers v6, then your type definitions would be

```js
declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: import('ethers').Eip1193Provider
  }
}
```

Note the use of the optional type `?`, forcing you to check if the browser indeed has metamask.

Answer (score 5):

Use `(window as any).ethereum.request` to get around type checking.

Answer (score 4):

You can try adding the following line at the beginning:

```
declare let window: any;
```

Then, you can do stuff like this:

```
import Web3 from 'web3';

//...

   let web3: Web3;
   if (window.ethereum) {
      web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
      // Ask User permission to connect to Metamask
      await window.ethereum.enable();
   };
```

Answer (score 3):

The answers thus far have been for `ethers` v5, here is how you do it for v6...

```typescript
import { ethers } from "ethers";
import { BrowserProvider, Eip1193Provider } from "ethers/types/providers";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum: Eip1193Provider & BrowserProvider;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys if you are using **`React`** with **`TypeScript`** just do this and everything goes right! **Trust me :)**

1. create **`global.d.ts`** in the root of your project and put this code

   ```
    declare global {
        interface Window {
            ethereum: import('ethers').providers.ExternalProvider;
        }
    }
   ```
2. Then in **`react-app-env.d.ts`** put this code

   ```
    interface Window {
        ethereum: any;
    }
   ```

Now you have the code snippet and no error!

Answer (score 0):

try with this.

```js
interface CustomWindow extends Window {
  ethereum?: any;
}

declare const window: CustomWindow;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the desired type lives in [@metamask/providers NPM library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@metamask/providers?activeTab=readme)
. I've solved the type issue by installing this lib in devDependencies:

```sh
npm i -D @metamask/providers
```

and extended a global Window interface

```
import { MetaMaskInpageProvider } from '@metamask/providers';

declare global {
  interface Window {
    ethereum?: MetaMaskInpageProvider;
  }
}
```

in `globals.d.ts`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Viem with Hardhat it might help if you create:

`src/types/index.d.ts` file:

```
export {}

type EthereumProvider = { request(...args: any): Promise<any> };

declare global {
    interface Window {
        ethereum?: EthereumProvider;
    }
}
```

Make sure to include `export {}` otherwise it wouldn't seem to work for me. Here's an article that could be helpful when debugging types: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-property-does-not-exist-on-type-window.

The definition of `EthereumProvider` is actually copied directly from Viem source code:

```
type EthereumProvider = { request(...args: any): Promise<any> }

// ...

export type CustomTransport = Transport<
  'custom',
  {},
  EthereumProvider['request']
>
```

Source: `viem/clients/transports/custom.ts`.