# Importing web3js library in react typescript web worker error: Uncaught ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: web3js, react, typescript

This is a copy of a question that I've asked on stack overflow but since I haven't gotten any feedback there I figured I'd try my luck here as well.

Link to stack overflow  question if you would rather answer it there:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74635069/importing-library-in-typescript-web-worker-error-uncaught-referenceerror-windo

I'm currently trying to run a web worker to check objects in ethereum smart contracts using web3. The web3 library references the window object on import somewhere in the code and thus errors out since the window object does not exist in the context of the web worker. I'm wondering if anyone has run into this problem, either with web3 or with other libraries referencing the window object and how you have solved this.

All libraries not using the window object seem to be importing fine and the web-worker is working when web3 related code in MyWorker.worker.ts is commented. I'm sure I could make changes within the web3js file itself to get it to play nice but that's a rabbit hole I don't want to go down for all the reasons I'm sure most of you are aware of.

I'm working off a repository created by a developer named Dominique Mueller, the code can be found here:

https://github.com/AkaashMukherjee/typescript-web-worker

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I had issues when implementing functionality in browsers where metamask is installed; window.ethereum is not recognized by typescript; I read your question and reminds me of that..  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/94468/99976 I hope we're talking about the same thing

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had a look and it seems the problem in the thread you suggested is that the window.ethereum property is missing when executed in the main thread. My problem is a little different in that I don't even have a window object and that the error is happening at the level of web3js and not my code.